# Drawing ECG in VB6.0

Tags: graph, vb6

Whether is it possible to draw ECG in VB6.0? As i am not that much familiar with VB any type of help will be appreciated.Please help me .thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if this questions was just "Drawing in VB6.0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method to do this is to use a picture box with the `AutoRedraw` property set to true and the `ScaleMode` set to `vbPixels`.

For each point, you calculate the Y value (dependant on the minimum and maximum allowable values). To make it scan, just increment the X value for each point you draw wrapping back to 0 when it gets to the width of the picture box (`.ScaleWidth`).

You can use the picture box's `.Line` method to blank the areas behind the current X point and the `.PSet` method to draw the new point.

```
Dim X As Long
Dim LastValue As Long

Private Sub AddPoint(ByVal Value As Long)
  'Clear the line behind (for 5 pixels forward)
  Picture1.Line (X, 0)-(X + 5, Picture1.ScaleHeight), vbBlack, BF

  'Draw the new point and the line from the previous point
  Picture1.Line (X - 1, LastValue)-(X, Value), vbGreen
  Picture1.PSet (X, Value), vbGreen

  'Update the last value so we can draw the line between them
  LastValue = Value

  'Increment the X value for the next point
  X = X + 1
  If X = Picture1.ScaleWidth Then X = 0
End Sub
```

A better method is to use an off screen picture that you update using a similar method and just update the picturebox when needed.